# Why is JEST showing escape characters for an expected assertion?

Tags: jestjs, graphql

I'm currently testing a graphQL query string, however when I run the test, it fails. I'm not sure why the escape character is getting added to my expected value, any thoughts?

```
const expected = `{"query": "mutation {
  anonymousConsentSet(
    input: {\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"address\":\"123 Main St\",\"phoneNumber\":\"123456677\",\"emailAddress\":\"test@test.com\"}
  )
}", "variables": ""}`;

const mockFormData = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  phone: '123456677',
  address: '123 Main St',
  email: 'test@test.com'
};
it('should get expected query', () => {
  const output: any =  createQuery(mockFormData);

  expect(output).toBe(expected);  // <------------This is failing because of unmatched escape characters
});
```

Notice the expected variable does not contain escape characters, so why is it showing after running the test below?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try casting both of them to `.toString()` . I had the same problem, but only when I used `.toContain` it showed me that I was actually comparing 2 different types.